# tcpdf portrait custom page size

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I wish to create a custom page size in TCPDF. For that I have the following piece of code:

```
$width      = 80;
$height         = 58; 
$pageLayout     = array($width, $height);
$pdf            = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

I am expecting a page of 80mm x 58mm. But the above code creates a page of 58mm width and 80mm height.

So instead of PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, I gave 'L' and it gave me the result right. But when I print the page from the browser, the print out comes rotated as would be expected of a Landmark orientation.

Does TCPDF create automatic portrait orientation by adjusting the width and the height?

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

As written in TCPDF docs, you can set PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION with 'P', or 'L', but also with an emptystring '', which, is the parameter to autoselect page orientation.

[TCPDF docs](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ad6a3575405b61049ff85ce019df5451d)

TCPDF, just set the page orientation from your TCPDF settings.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but IMHO not a complete answer.

Just encountered this problem with custom label sizes.
Yes, you can set the page orientation from within your code.
But TCPDF likes to be in landscape modus when `width > height` and swaps the dimensions allthough you want portrait orientation.

See these lines in [tcpdf->setPageOrientation()](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/42cd0f9786af7e5db4fcedaa66f717b0d0032320/tcpdf.php#L2254)

```
if ($this->fwPt > $this->fhPt) {
...
if ((abs($this->pagedim[$this->page]['MediaBox']['urx'] - $this->hPt) < $this->feps) AND (abs($this->pagedim[$this->page]['MediaBox']['ury'] - $this->wPt) < $this->feps)){
            // swap X and Y coordinates (change page orientation)
```

A good workaround to create printable pdfs on 57x32mm labels is to set page orientation to landscape yourself, then the generated pdf is printable from within a webbrowser and Acrobat Reader.

```
$width = 80;
$height = 58; 

$orientation = 'P';
$pageLayout = array($width, $height);
if($width > $height){
    $orientation = 'L';
    // optionally swap dimensions yourself and rotate it:
    // $pageLayout = array($height, $width, 'Rotate' => 90);
}

$pdf = new TCPDF($orientation, PDF_UNIT, $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

**Note:** my label printer is set to print in portrait modus, the labels come out with the longest side first (landscape). To print the above created pdf, I have to select 'portrait modus' (or 'automatic') in the print dialog from the webbrowser or Acrobat Reader, allthough the pdf itself is 'landscape orientated'. When you swap the dimensions and rotate, I'll have to select 'landscape' (or 'automatic') in the print dialog.